# Spring WebFlux FilePart transferTo method can't write file to dest path

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

```
import org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.FilePart;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.io.File;

@RestController
public class TestController {

    @PostMapping("test")
    public Mono<R> test(FilePart file){
        String fileName = file.filename();
        File newFile = new File("F:/images/banner/",fileName);
        file.transferTo(newFile);
        return Mono.just(R.ok());
    }
}
```

i upload picture and use transferTo method to write file to the dest path.
but i can't found the picture in the **F:/images/banner/**
someone can help me? thanks

Comment: Because you don't subscribe. You are writing reactive code, if you don't subscribe nothing will happen. What you should do is something like `return file.transferTo(newFile).then(Mono.just(R.ok());`

Answer (score 3):

When writing reactive code you have to make sure it terminates, or in other words you need to subscribe to the publisher. The [`file.transferTo()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/codec/multipart/FilePart.html) returns a `Mono<Void>` which, if you don't subscribe, doesn't actually do anything.

What you can do in your case is the following, use the `then` method to return your result.

```java
@PostMapping("test")
public Mono<R> test(FilePart file){
    String fileName = file.filename();
    File newFile = new File("F:/images/banner/",fileName);
    return file.transferTo(newFile)
      .then(Mono.just(R.ok()));
}
```

Now you return the call chain and the client will subscribe and things will start to happen. You could also add an additional `onError` call to return a error response when something breaks in the transfer.